# Snort3 no muestra alarmas cuando está capturando

Tags: linux, seguridad, configuración

Estoy intentando usar snort3 en una máquina de VirtualBox versión 7.0.10 con Debian 12, pero no consigo que muestre las alarmas en pantalla ni genere logs.

Instalé snort3 usando este script:

```
# actualizar
sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade -y
# Instalar las librerías que faltan

sudo apt install pkg-config autopoint flex check libpcre3-dev openssl libssl-dev cmake bison liblzma-dev libtool libpcap-dev -y

mkdir ~/apps
cd ~/apps

#libdaq
git clone https://github.com/snort3/libdaq
cd libdaq
./bootstrap
./configure
make
sudo make install
cd ..

#libdnet
git clone https://github.com/dugsong/libdnet.git
cd libdnet
./configure
make
sudo make install
cd ..

#hwloc
git clone https://github.com/open-mpi/hwloc
cd hwloc
./autogen.sh
./configure
make
sudo make install
cd ..

#luajit
git clone https://luajit.org/git/luajit.git
cd luajit
make
sudo make install
sudo ln -sf luajit-2.1.0-beta3 /usr/local/bin/luajit
cd ..

#libpcap
git clone https://github.com/the-tcpdump-group/libpcap
cd libpcap
./autogen.sh
./configure
make
sudo make install
cd ..

#pcre
git clone https://github.com/PCRE2Project/pcre2.git
cd pcre2
./autogensh
./configure
make
sudo make install
cd ..

#snort3
mkdir snort
git clone https://github.com/snort3/snort3.git
cd snort3
./configure_cmake.sh
cd build
sudo make -j $(nproc) install
cd ~
```

Se instala correctamente.

```
--------------------------------------------------
o")~   Snort++ 3.1.67.0
--------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------
Network Policy : policy id 0 : 
--------------------------------------------------
Inspection Policy : policy id 0 : 
--------------------------------------------------
pcap DAQ configured to passive.
--------------------------------------------------
host_cache
    memcap: 8388608 bytes

Snort successfully validated the configuration (with 0 warnings).
o")~   Snort exiting
```

Se instala en /usr/local/snort

Además, descargo las reglas de la comunidad de la página oficial de snort.

Después, habilito el modo promiscuo en la configuración de red de la máquina virtual. La configuración la tengo en "adaptador puente".

En la terminal, ejecuto:

`sudo ip link set enp0s3 promisc on`

Después, ejecuto snort con el siguiente comando:

```
sudo /usr/local/snort/bin/snort -c /usr/local/snort/etc/snort/snort.lua -i enp0s3 -R ~/Descargas/snort3-rules/snort3-community.rules
```

y muestra:

```
--------------------------------------------------
o")~   Snort++ 3.1.67.0
--------------------------------------------------
Loading /usr/local/snort/etc/snort/snort.lua:
Loading snort_defaults.lua:
Finished snort_defaults.lua:
        cip
        iec104
        modbus
        dce_smb
        dce_tcp
        dce_http_proxy
        dce_http_server
        gtp_inspect
        smtp
        ftp_server
        ftp_data
        http2_inspect
        appid
        wizard
        binder
        ips
        file_id
        ftp_client
        http_inspect
        js_norm
        file_policy
        references
        classifications
        port_scan
        dce_udp
        s7commplus
        mms
        dnp3
        trace
        ssh
        netflow
        imap
        output
        active
        alerts
        daq
        decode
        host_cache
        host_tracker
        hosts
        network
        packets
        process
        search_engine
        so_proxy
        stream
        stream_ip
        stream_icmp
        stream_tcp
        stream_udp
        stream_user
        stream_file
        arp_spoof
        back_orifice
        dns
        normalizer
        pop
        rpc_decode
        sip
        ssl
        telnet
Finished /usr/local/snort/etc/snort/snort.lua:
Loading file_id.rules_file:
Loading file_magic.rules:
Finished file_magic.rules:
Finished file_id.rules_file:
Loading rule args:
Loading /home/lenin/Descargas/snort3-rules/snort3-community.rules:
Finished /home/lenin/Descargas/snort3-rules/snort3-community.rules:
Finished rule args:
--------------------------------------------------
ips policies rule stats
              id  loaded  shared enabled    file
               0    4229       0    4229    /usr/local/snort/etc/snort/snort.lua
--------------------------------------------------
rule counts
       total rules loaded: 4229
               text rules: 4229
            option chains: 4229
            chain headers: 287
                 flowbits: 48
     flowbits not checked: 23
--------------------------------------------------
port rule counts
             tcp     udp    icmp      ip
     any     473      58     147      22
     src     170      15       0       0
     dst     776     151       0       0
    both       6      11       0       0
   total    1425     235     147      22
--------------------------------------------------
service rule counts          to-srv  to-cli
                   dcerpc:       72      20
                     dhcp:        2       2
                      dns:       28       7
                  file_id:      208     208
                      ftp:       90       4
                 ftp-data:        1      97
                     http:     2082     256
                    http2:     2082     256
                    http3:     2082     256
                     imap:       35     118
                      irc:        5       2
                 kerberos:        5       0
                     ldap:        0       1
                    mysql:        3       0
              netbios-dgm:        1       1
               netbios-ns:        4       3
              netbios-ssn:       69      17
                     nntp:        2       0
                     pop3:       23     118
                      rdp:        5       0
                      sip:        5       5
                     smtp:      130       2
                     snmp:       18       7
                     ssdp:        3       0
                      ssl:       20      42
                   sunrpc:       68       4
                   telnet:       12       6
                     tftp:        1       0
                     wins:        1       0
                    total:     7057    1432
--------------------------------------------------
fast pattern groups
                      src: 114
                      dst: 312
                      any: 8
                to_server: 72
                to_client: 49
--------------------------------------------------
search engine (ac_bnfa)
                instances: 338
                 patterns: 10777
            pattern chars: 175025
               num states: 123102
         num match states: 10499
             memory scale: MB
             total memory: 3.68233
           pattern memory: 0.577704
        match list memory: 1.33421
        transition memory: 1.72915
        fast pattern only: 7103
appid: MaxRss diff: 3020
appid: patterns loaded: 300
--------------------------------------------------
pcap DAQ configured to passive.
Commencing packet processing
++ [0] enp0s3
```

Desde otra máquina virtual, ejecuto ping a la ip de la máquina que está ejecutando snort3, también nmap. Y no muestra nada. Interrumpo la ejecución con ctrl + c. Y muestra:

```
== stopping
-- [0] enp0s3
--------------------------------------------------
Packet Statistics
--------------------------------------------------
daq
                 received: 331285
                 analyzed: 331284
              outstanding: 1
                    allow: 330953
                whitelist: 331
                 rx_bytes: 345231970
--------------------------------------------------
codec
                    total: 331284       (100.000%)
                    other: 29           (  0.009%)
                 discards: 205348       ( 61.985%)
                      arp: 329          (  0.099%)
                      eth: 331284       (100.000%)
                    icmp4: 10           (  0.003%)
                 icmp4_ip: 2            (  0.001%)
                    icmp6: 184          (  0.056%)
                     igmp: 8            (  0.002%)
                     ipv4: 15800        (  4.769%)
                     ipv6: 315123       ( 95.122%)
            ipv6_hop_opts: 31           (  0.009%)
                      llc: 3            (  0.001%)
                      tcp: 125921       ( 38.010%)
                      udp: 3779         (  1.141%)
--------------------------------------------------
Module Statistics
--------------------------------------------------
appid
                  packets: 125575
        processed_packets: 125101
          ignored_packets: 474
           total_sessions: 1641
       service_cache_adds: 262
             bytes_in_use: 39824
             items_in_use: 262
--------------------------------------------------
arp_spoof
                  packets: 329
--------------------------------------------------
back_orifice
                  packets: 2895
--------------------------------------------------
binder
              raw_packets: 201856
                new_flows: 1634
          service_changes: 127
                 inspects: 203490
--------------------------------------------------
detection
                 analyzed: 331284
               hard_evals: 221356
             raw_searches: 60951
          cooked_searches: 5407
             pkt_searches: 66358
             pdu_searches: 13627
            file_searches: 1354
                   alerts: 24
             total_alerts: 24
                   logged: 24
--------------------------------------------------
dns
                  packets: 268
                 requests: 134
                responses: 134
--------------------------------------------------
file_id
              total_files: 677
          total_file_data: 228227
     max_concurrent_files: 1
--------------------------------------------------
http_inspect
                    flows: 26
                    scans: 7865
              reassembles: 7863
              inspections: 7817
                 requests: 2896
                responses: 674
             get_requests: 2890
            post_requests: 6
           request_bodies: 6
       uri_normalizations: 526
               uri_coding: 12
  max_concurrent_sessions: 6
          pipelined_flows: 16
       pipelined_requests: 1690
              total_bytes: 1334130
--------------------------------------------------
normalizer
        test_tcp_trim_win: 11324
          test_tcp_ts_nop: 31
           test_tcp_block: 12
--------------------------------------------------
pcre
               pcre_rules: 1083
              pcre_native: 1083
--------------------------------------------------
port_scan
                  packets: 129902
                 trackers: 237
--------------------------------------------------
search_engine
               max_queued: 13
            total_flushed: 7253
            total_inserts: 7540
             total_unique: 7253
     non_qualified_events: 228587
         qualified_events: 22
           searched_bytes: 79839245
--------------------------------------------------
ssl
                  packets: 975
                  decoded: 975
             client_hello: 86
             server_hello: 52
              certificate: 1
              server_done: 58
      client_key_exchange: 36
      server_key_exchange: 1
            change_cipher: 132
       client_application: 426
       server_application: 342
                    alert: 25
     unrecognized_records: 30
     handshakes_completed: 11
         sessions_ignored: 15
  max_concurrent_sessions: 59
--------------------------------------------------
stream
                    flows: 1634
             total_prunes: 16
idle_prunes_proto_timeout: 16
--------------------------------------------------
stream_icmp
                 sessions: 32
                      max: 32
                  created: 32
                 released: 32
--------------------------------------------------
stream_ip
                 sessions: 2
                      max: 2
                  created: 4
                 released: 4
                 timeouts: 2
              total_bytes: 128
--------------------------------------------------
stream_tcp
                 sessions: 1246
                      max: 1246
                  created: 1246
                 released: 1245
                 timeouts: 8
             instantiated: 1238
                   setups: 1246
                 restarts: 127
         discards_skipped: 12
          invalid_seq_num: 17
              invalid_ack: 20
                   events: 12
             syn_trackers: 1115
         syn_ack_trackers: 122
            data_trackers: 8
              segs_queued: 11957
            segs_released: 11957
                segs_used: 4543
          rebuilt_packets: 8962
          rebuilt_buffers: 33
            rebuilt_bytes: 1933025
                     gaps: 149
        exceeded_max_segs: 11306
          client_cleanups: 43
          server_cleanups: 5
                  closing: 1
                     syns: 1115
                 syn_acks: 235
                   resets: 1207
                     fins: 292
      inspector_fallbacks: 1
        partial_fallbacks: 47
                 max_segs: 3072
                max_bytes: 4090466
          zero_win_probes: 1
--------------------------------------------------
stream_udp
                 sessions: 354
                      max: 354
                  created: 359
                 released: 359
                 timeouts: 5
              total_bytes: 2140471
--------------------------------------------------
tcp
        bad_tcp4_checksum: 2445
        bad_tcp6_checksum: 998
--------------------------------------------------
udp
        bad_udp4_checksum: 351
        bad_udp6_checksum: 533
--------------------------------------------------
wizard
                tcp_scans: 171
                 tcp_hits: 127
                udp_scans: 234
               udp_misses: 234
--------------------------------------------------
Appid Statistics
--------------------------------------------------
detected apps and services
              Application: Services   Clients    Users      Payloads   Misc       Referred  
                  unknown: 549        124        0          116        0          0         
--------------------------------------------------
Summary Statistics
--------------------------------------------------
process
                  signals: 1
--------------------------------------------------
timing
                  runtime: 00:25:14
                  seconds: 1514.571764
o")~   Snort exiting
```

Muestra que detectó aplicaciones y servicios, pero durante la captura no muestra nada, ninguna alarma, ningún mensaje. Tampoco encuentro ningún directorio snort.log.xxxxx.

No sé qué está fallando.